# Manipulating and saving a vector image

Tags: javascript, xml, html, dom, svg

I created an online tool that uses javascript to manipulate elements of a supplied SVG image. I'm having issues in accessing the DOM,When I have the image in an object tag. But that prevents you from right clicking the image in a browser and clicking save. So I put image in an img tag.now I can't access the DOM. Canvas seems to also disable right click and save

What could be the possible issue and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are having an issue with.

Comment: I didn't think the code would help much since this is a theory question, but I'll put something in there.

Comment: Whoever edited my question and completely changed the meaning without my permission, please put it back the way it was! >:(

Comment: I rolled back the question for you, once it is reviewed your question should be back how it was. In order for us to help you, you should include valid code to reproduce the issue you are having. Also be sure to take a look at what is [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here at SO.